# Run function in specific time with milliseconds precision

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, milliseconds

I try to run a function at a specific time with milliseconds precision, but every method I use have some delays and its not even a constant delay(e.g its varied between 30 to 90 milliseconds).

here is one of my codes

```
tt = datetime(2021, 8, 22, 3, 17, 00) #desired time
time.sleep((time.mktime(tt.timetuple())) - time.time())
print(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

and its output is :

```
03:17:00.038
```

as you can see it has .038 sec delay. I also tried `pause` and it was the same.
Is there a way to eliminate this delay or make it constant ?

Comment: How long are your sleeps?

Comment: Delays have many sources. For one, you are running some code after the sleep in order to compute the current time, so that code takes a bit of time. But I'm only getting a 0.003 second delay running your code. I think it's likely that your computer is just spending time on background tasks and other threads; these unavoidable variable delays are the cost of using a multitasking computer. Maybe try closing other applications?

Comment: @KellyBundy I use sleep to add delays till the time I want to code to continue, it's about 2 to 3 minutes though

Answer (score 3):

This is the nature of a non-real-time operating system.  if you ask for a 3ms delay, in order to achieve exactly that, the operating system would have to get an interrupt 3ms from now to wake you up.  They don't do that.  Instead, there is a regular timer interrupt, during which the scheduler re-evaluates all of the running threads to see who should run next.  During that evaluation, it checks to see if any timers have expired.

The schedule interval varies by operating system.  On Windows, it is 16ms.  On Linux, it is a bit more complicated, and there are several different scheduler algorithms; historically it was 100ms, adjustable downward.

`time.sleep` and the like only guarantee that you will sleep for AT LEAST as long as you request.  On Windows, if you request 10ms, you will sleep for at least 16ms, because your timer won't be checked until the scheduler interval.

That's the way it is.  You need to work with it.

Comment: *"On Windows, if you request 10ms, you will sleep for at least 16ms"* - I just tried [this](https://tio.run/##bY6xCsMwDER3f4VGG9pgk6UE@iUhhNDKraG2hawM/XrXdZYOve2OpzvRW545jRfiWj3nCBIiQoiUWYCQ/XrLexLkE5QXIin1BQpcYV6UzwwrhAS8pQdqZ601k4ImsY34Pdem571D28G6w4v7z/WRYSPCdNcNOrdGc0wPpb3WMOKQRPdonsbF1PoB) on my Windows PC and got `[0.008437299999059178, 0.008581000001868233, 0.009686100005637854]`. So apparently it not only doesn't sleep at least 16ms but not even at least the requested 10ms. Is `sleep` misbehaving or is `perf_counter` too inaccurate?

Answer (score 1):

Like it was mentioned time.sleep sets a minimum time, but could be more depending on what else the OS scheduler implementation (heck, on Linux you get to pick between multiple schedulers) and is doing and what other programs you have been running. If the timer resolution is 1 ms, you could get control back after 20 ms or more, and who knows maybe it could even return control a bit before the requested time

However unlike what was said before, starting with Win 7 the default schedule interval is 1 ms. You could have requested that interval, but now you don't even have to

The most accurate timer in Python is time.perf_counter_ns. If you use the float variant, resolution go over 1ms after a bit more an hour. Second most accurate is time.perf_counter

The most accurate way to run a function is with a busy loop, however that will max CPU core usage and waste energy. Second best is wait() on threads, but at this moment Python only provides floating point versions, but if you keep track of the timer with perf_counter_ns() you should be able to measure as accurately as possible how much time has passed and can adjust the values passed to wait() with that

I know this is an old question, but just wanted to correct the default tick interval on new Windows versions, as knowing that would have saved me hours of tinkering with something I didn't need to fix anymore